# ASP.Net MVC and working with a designer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, compilation

I'm working on a site with a designer.  She is on a Mac, and isn't a programmer.  However, she's very smart and can read code pretty well.

When I push an MVC site, I have to build it and when I publish, it doesn't push the Controllers folder, because it's compiled into the bin directory.

Is there a way that I can not compile it, but just let IIS recompile the site as needed (like how you can do with a pure WebForms project?)

Comment: No. Views aside, MVC is an app in the classic sense (as borland C++ would be). The Views aren't built for practical reasons (build time), but the rest is the app.

Comment: Matt, read this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502956/asp-net-mvc-project-not-compiling-on-iis

Comment: Thanks @DaveA.  I realize that I need to rethink a bit of how we will do projects together in the future.  I had this same misunderstanding with Web Site vs. Web Project.